# Naming thumbnails in ffmpeg

Tags: terminal, ffmpeg, ubuntu-14.04

I am using ffmpeg to generate thumbnails each time there is a scene change in any given video clip. I want to know how I could name each thumbnail with  a timestamp of where it appears in the video clip. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

This is the code I am using which works really well but just gives the thumbnails a sequential number.

```
ffmpeg -i test5.mov -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.3)" -vsync vfr out%02d.jpg
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's an answer than satisfies me. It burns a timestamp on each  of the thumbnails created. Thanks to [ffmpeg's forum](http://ffmpeg.gusari.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=2859&p=8573#p8573)

```
ffmpeg -i input.mov -vf "select=gt(scene\,0.4),drawtext=fontfile=fontfile.ttf:fontsize=50:x=W-tw-10:y=H-th-10:text='%{pts\:hms}' " -vsync vfr out%02d.jpg
```